# Marklogic questions

Tags: marklogic

Hello I am a SQL Server DBA and I am new to MarkLogic and I have a few questions.

1. would MarkLogic support .net framework. By this I meant our developers are using .net framework 4.5 and using LINQ to generate scripts for sql. Would they be able to generate MarkLogic scripts for performing CRUD operations against MarkLogic database?
2. Would I be able to run sql or sql like scripts to retrieve data from MarkLogic database( selecting documents with sql). I know CouchBase supports something like niql.
3. does horizontal scaling require the entire cluster to be down? Would I be able to add or remove a node to a MarkLogic cluster while the cluster is still online?
4. Does MarkLogic support point in time restore (database and document). SQLServer has the concept of Transaction log backups and they let me do a point in time restore. Are there anything similar to that?
5. I won't be moving the entire application to MarkLogic rather only part of it where SQLServer is having contention. So it will be a hybrid model. Will there be any issue with two phase commits? (I meant commits from SQLServer as well as commits from MarkLogic)
6. Is there a minimum number of nodes required for purchasing the license? and also what are the minimum number of nodes required for a cluster?

Comment: There could be a dozen reasons for choosing MarkLogic or Couchbase depending on final needs. But in any case, they are far from the same solution...  http://db-engines.com/en/system/Couchbase%3BMarkLogic

Comment: I kindly suggest using separate SO questions for each question you have next time. Easier with voting, and providing alternative answers in case one of them has multiple..

Answer (score 6):

A document database is not the same as a relational database. Comparing them and expecting your existing tooling just to work is an unlikely scenerio.

1) MarkLogic can store XML as one of the document sources. LINQ has some level of XML support (I do not know LINQ - just read a tutorial). But this appears that you have what may be an acceptable starting point.

2) MarkLogic does have a SQL layer - but its more for BI needs. I suggest you look more deeply into the robust REST API or XCC.net options and robust search features and embrace the full features of MarkLogic.

3) Clusters need not go down for adding or removing nodes. There are other configuration changes that require host restarts, but not the items you mention.

But keep in mind, there are other ways to scale depending on the need - like adding additional data forests, so scaling need not always = new node..

4) Yes. You can rollback a forest (your data) to a particular point in time using the journal.  Details can be found here: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/backup_restore#id_21622

5) No transational database likes transactions to stay open for a long time. As long as you can adhere to that, there is good news. In MarkLogic, you can even do multi-statement transactions over the REST API using multiple REST calls (https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/transactions). So I believe you are well covered here.

But also keep in mind that there are ways to make MarkLogic talk to your SQL server directly - so you may very well have other options when designing the integreated solution.  (https://developer.marklogic.com/code/mlsam)

6) The minimum number of nodes can be discussed with Sales from MarkLogic - but yes, there are single-node installs.

For 'Cluster', it depends on what you mean. But if you are considering HA, Then you need 3 nodes to get the data redundancy.

Comment: Just a comment to build on David's point #2.  When I helped a large company migrate part of an application from SQLServer to MarkLogic, part of the rationale was to remove their lucene layer to simplify their architecture.  Once you think of the benefits of search access (especially faceted search), I agree you may not always reach for SQL as the primary data access mechanism.